# Version control app/manifest-merger-release-report.txt?

Tags: android, android-studio

When generating signed APKs from the Build menu I end up with the new file `app/manifest-merger-release-report.txt`. What is this file and should it be version controlled (like ProGuard's `mapping.txt`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file is generated by the manifest merging step of the Android build. If you're doing a sophisticated build where multiple flavors and build types are coming into play, and especially if you're directing traffic during the merge by explicitly telling the build system how to handle specific manifest attributes, you may find the report useful.

It's not necessary to save this file, since it's only of use if you're trying to diagnose problems during the build. It's not like the Proguard mapping file, which you may need to keep so you can de-obfuscate errors and stack traces that come in from the wild.